# how to share the exported whatsapp docunment to react-native app

Tags: android, react-native

I'm new to React native and I want to export my whatsapp chat and share it to my react native app.

There are two packages that can help:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-file-share-intent
https://github.com/meedan/react-native-share-menu.

I tried with the second package because the first package is not working if we use react-navigation so I installed second package, it is working perfectly fine, but after I'm facing two issues:

1. If I'm using this package the home-screen icon is not created, I don't know why the icon not created in the home screen, but its placed in the share indent
2. When I tried to share the text document from the file manager, react native app icon is placed in the share indent and also it's working perfectly. But the same thing I tried it in whats app means it doesn't work. I think when I export from WhatsApp initially its created as a temporary file. That's why my app is not displayed in that sharing indent.

I pushed my code in GitHub repo and the link for the repo is: 
https://github.com/BalaRajendran/sharemenu-reactnative

App.js - https://github.com/BalaRajendran/sharemenu-reactnative/blob/master/App.js

```
 export default class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          fileUrl: null,
        };
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        if (RNFileShareIntent) {
          RNFileShareIntent.getFilepath((url) => {
            this.setState({ fileUrl: url });
          })
        }
      }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.sharemenu">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"  
        >
        <intent-filter>
            ///changed code according to react-native-share-menu
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PICK"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/*" />
            <data android:mimeType="image/*" /> 
            <data android:mimeType="file/*" /> 
            <data android:mimeType="application/*" />
             //
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

so can you please help me with my problem,

Comment: Share to us your code here

Comment: single or multiple images sharing using react-native-share, answer by me with more detailed info here, checkout  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67016851/want-to-share-multiple-images-with-separate-caption-to-each-image-whatsapp-reac/67167916#67167916